# Double-displaying a post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, posts

I want to display 2 posts in one way, and then below that I want them reappear inline with all the other posts on the site.

If i do it the way i thought i should, then i gets all messed up.

I have uploaded my index.php-file to http://pastebin.com/tmfpaAhc

Revisions is appreciated! We're going live tonight :O

Thanks, Jonas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 loops, the one that you've done and another using get_posts. More about get_posts: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Ahhhhh!! Thanks alot! Sorry bout the lame question then:)

Comment: Please, check the answer as correct, if you've found it is.
And, if you have more questions, "just do it" :)